# Swagger-codegen not generating enums as enum type

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have an enum in my swagger scheme which looks like the following:

```
- name: shipmentType
      in: query
      required: false
      type: integer
      format: int32
      enum:
        - 0
        - 1
        - 2
        - 3
        - 4
        - 5
        - 6
```

After generating the typescript-angular client with swagger codegen (2.4.17), the generated enum looks like the following picture:

[image]

is there any way to make the generator use the typescript enum type instead of creating a custom object?

Comment: I have the same issue, this seems to have to do with the angular typescript generator as the underlying JSON is OpenAPI v3 + it actually defines it as an enum. Although the JSON does not define any semantic labels... Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

It seems once I set `stringEnums` to true in the [openapi-generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-angular/), it actually generates enums and not `type`

Comment: omg thanks for finding this. I don't understand how this is not the default!